# Найти максимум одномерного массива c помощью рекурсии C++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Не знаю как сделать поиск максимального элемента массива с помощью рекурсии. Есть идеи?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
const int n = 5;
float a[n + 1];
int fmax(float a[], int nach, int kon); 

int main() {
    int i, k; for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cout << "\n введи a[" << i << "] ";
        cin >> a[i];
    } for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cout << " a[" << i << "]=" << a[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << fmax(a[5], 0, 4); return(0);
}
int fmax(float a[], int nach, int kon)
{
    int k, kmax;
    float max; 
    kmax = nach;
    max = a[nach]; 
    for(k = nach; k <= kon; k++)
    {
        if(a[k] > max)
        {
            max = a[k]; kmax = k;
        }
    } 
    return kmax;
}
```

Comment: почему такие странные домашние задания дают, неужели нельзя придумать задачу, где рекурсия хоть как-то осмыслена :(

Comment: Сам не понимаю. Который день над ней думаю.

Comment: @splash58 Например, для такого контейнера как `std::map` рекурсивный поиск минимума/максимума очень даже удобен. Какая у вас страктура хранения данных? И приведите хоть попытку реализации поиска.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive я на всяких си уже сто лет не писал. а он линейно не проходится?

Comment: @SergoE нажмите "править" и положите в вопрос код

Comment: Спасибо, кто добавил код. Но как мне нужно было это сделать?

Comment: @SergoE, нужно было нажать «править» около вопроса, потом вставить код и в редакторе(выделив код) нажать на фигурные скобки(код)

Comment: @ixSci Благодарю за помощь. Я не вижу в комментариях редактора.

Comment: @SergoE, редактировать надо не комментарий, а вопрос. В комментарии помещать код не нужно

Comment: @splash58 проходится, просто при рекурсивном обходе там получается код в одну строчку посредством `std::max` и тернарного оператора :D

Comment: @StateItPrimitive увидел ваш комментарий. так вон в комментариях к ответу на обычном линейном массиве так же получается

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как и для других рекурсивных функций, достаточно реализовать простейший случай и вызвать эту же функцию с меньшей задачей:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt max_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, ForwardIt largest)
{
  if (first == last)  // no more elements to compare
    return largest;

  if (*largest < *first) // compare with the first element
    largest = first;

  ++first;
  return max_element(first, last, largest); // compare the rest
}
```

<sup>если слово `template` не ясно, то чтобы не отвлекаться (это не важно для понимания рекурсии), можно просто заменить `ForwardIt` на `float*`.</sup>

Простейшим случаем здесь является пустой массив (`first == last`), в этом случае функция просто возвращает `largest` аргумент.

Чтобы уменьшить размер задачи, можно отбросить первый элемент `first`—обновив `largest`, если необходимо—и вызвать функцию рекурсивно c остатками ввода, чтобы завершить решение задачи.

Для удобства использования, можно определить функцию с двумя параметрами, передав`first` в качестве начального значения для `largest`—это работает и для пустых массивов, в этом случае возвращается значение равное `last`:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt max_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
  return max_element(first, last, first);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  float a[] = {1, -2, 3, 0.5};
  std::cout << *max_element(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)) << '\n';
}
```

Чтобы запустить:

```
$ g++ max_recursive.cc && ./a.out
3
```

---

В данном случае `max_element()` является так называемой tail-recursive функцией—рекурсивный вызов является хвостовым (последним) в функции и может не потреблять стек. Некоторые компиляторы умеют автоматически преобразовывать подобный код в циклы, например, [`gcc -O2` для `ForwardIt=int*` может сгенерировать вот такой ассемблер](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O2',source:'int*+max_element(int*+first,+int*+last,+int*+largest%29%0A%7B%0A++if+(first+%3D%3D+last%29++//+no+more+elements+to+compare%0A++++return+largest%3B%0A%0A++if+(*largest+%3C+*first%29+//+compare+with+the+first+element%0A++++largest+%3D+first%3B%0A%0A++%2B%2Bfirst%3B%0A++return+max_element(first,+last,+largest%29%3B+//+compare+the+rest%0A%7D%0A++'%29%29,filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t%29,version:3):

```assembler
                                    #   first  : %rdi
                                    #   last   : %rsi
                                    #   largest: %rdx
                                    #   result : %rax

max_element(int*, int*, int*):
        cmpq    %rsi, %rdi          # x = cmp(first, last)
        movq    %rdx, %rax          # result = largest
        je      .L2                 # if(first == last) return result // if(!x)
.L4:                                # do {
        movl    (%rdi), %ecx        # y = *first
        cmpl    %ecx, (%rax)        # z = cmp(*result, y)
        cmovl   %rdi, %rax          # if (*result < y) result = first //if(z<0)
        addq    $4, %rdi            # ++first
        cmpq    %rdi, %rsi          # x = cmp(last, first)
        jne     .L4                 # } while (last != first) // while(x)
.L2:
        rep ret                     # return result // rep is amd
                                                    // brancher bug workaround
```

*Абсолютно такой же* код получается [из итеративной версии](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O2',source:'int*+max_element(int*+first,+int*+last,+int*+largest%29%0A%7B%0A++for+(+%3B+first+!!%3D+last%3B+%2B%2Bfirst%29+%0A++++if+(*largest+%3C+*first%29+%0A++++++largest+%3D+first%3B++%0A++%0A++return+largest%3B%0A%7D%0A++'%29%29,filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t%29,version:3):

```
int* max_element(int* first, int* last, int* largest)
{
  for ( ; first != last; ++first) 
    if (*largest < *first) 
      largest = first;  

  return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно, например, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int max(const std::vector<int>::const_iterator& begin, std::vector<int>::const_iterator& end, int curentMax)
{
    if(begin == end)
        return curentMax;
    if(*begin > curentMax)
        return max(begin + 1, end, *begin);
    return max(begin + 1, end, curentMax);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array{1, 55, 17, 77, 88, 13, 45, 72, 11};
    std::cout << max(array.сbegin(), array.сend(), std::numeric_limits<int>::min()) << "\n";
}
```

Есть массив,— вектор, в котором находится некоторый набор данных. Я в функцию `max` передаю итераторы(можно считать указатели) на начало и конец(на одну позицию за концом) массива. Базовым случаем рекурсии будет случай, когда элементы массива кончились, т.е. начало и конец, переданные в аргументах, совпадают. В рекурсивном шаге мы проверяем, является ли элемент, который находится в начала переданного промежутка большим, по отношению к уже найденному максимальному, если да, то используем его, если нет, то используем ранее найденный `max`.

Comment: У меня к сожалению не такой набор знаний, чтобы понимать ваш код.

Comment: @SergoE, а что непонятного?

Comment: Мои знания меньше чем вы предполагаете. Я должен использовать `using namespace std` и рекурсию задавать с помощью обыкновенной функции, а так `return` можно использовать лишь раз.

Comment: @SergoE, я могу полностью за Вас написать вариант, который Вы сможете пойти и сдать, но кто здесь учится я или Вы, будет ли толк в том, что Вы ни в чём не разберётесь? В рекурсивной функции всегда будет не менее 2-х `return`ов, один на базовый случай, другой на рекурсивный. Можно, конечно, использовать вместо возвращаемого значение выходную ссылку, но это, во-первых, сложнее, во-вторых, криво.

Comment: *В рекурсивной функции всегда будет не менее 2- returnов* - чейто?

Comment: вот на птичьем языке - `function fmax(ar, b, e) {
   if (b < e) n = fmax(ar, b+1, e);
   return max(ar[b], n)
}`

Comment: @splash58, да, что-то не подумал я про отдельную переменную. Т.е. номинально у нас будет один `return`, но суть от этого не сильно изменится.

Comment: ну, я придираюсь к словам. вы же мальчику жизнь сломаете - он так преподавателю и скажет.

Comment: ну и всяко мне код с тремя ретурнами не очень нравится :) вот и выделываюсь

Comment: `function fmax(ar, b, e) {
   return (b<e) ? max(ar[b], fmax(ar, b+1, e)) : ar[b]);
}` - это без переменной

Comment: в порядке шутки, на одной олимпиаде было задание написать стандартный алгоритм Флойда без использования циклов условий и ещё чего-то, вот одно из решений https://ideone.com/vnGkjb (моё).

Comment: @pavel я вижу логические операторы и хвостовые рекурсивные вызовы в вашем коде (ветвление и циклы другими словами).  В тему: есть C компилятор, который генерирует код только с одной asm инструкцией ([mov на x86](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator/)). Более того, можно производить вычисления вообще не выполняя ни одной инструкции на CPU: [page faults являются Turing complete](https://github.com/jbangert/trapcc)

Answer (score 4):

Вот еще вариант для *массива* (не вектора), с делением такового пополам (быстрее от этого, конечно, он не работает :))

```
// Максимальный элемент в массиве array с индексами [start,stop)
int maxel(int * array, int start, int stop)
{
    if (start == stop-1) return array[start];
    int mid = (start + stop)/2;
    int m1 = maxel(array,start,mid), m2 = maxel(array,mid,stop);
    return (m1 > m2) ? m1 : m2;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int x[] = { 1,2,15,2,41,18,-4,2 };
    cout << maxel(x,0,sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]));
}
```

Comment: может и работает, т.к. глубина рекурсии log(N) а не N ==> меньше накладных расходов, и вылет по стеку тоже не грозит.

Comment: @pavel Ну разве что в этом смысле. Я имел в виду, что все равно O(N).

Comment: на среднем элементе - три вызова функции :)

Comment: @pavel: недостаток  у этой версии, что не очевидно работает ли она ([большинство программистов ошибаются, реализуя двоичный поиск](https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/), на который код в ответе похож без причины), и рекурсивный вызов не является хвостовым, поэтому компилятор не может в цикл его преобразовать. Как в [моём ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519147/23044) так и [в ответе @ixSci](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519106/23044) хвостовые рекурсивные вызовы используются, поэтому оптимизация возможна.

Answer (score 3):

Как рекурсию всегда можно представить итерацией, так и наоборот.

В своем примере поиска максимума Вы используя итерацию перебираете все элементы массива, соответственно простейшим будет вот такой естественный "однострочник" с рекурсией, возвращающий максимум:

```
float rfmax (float *a, int n, float cmax) {
  return n > 0 ? rfmax(a + 1, --n, cmax > *a ? cmax : *a) : cmax;
}
```

который на каждом следующем шаге рекурсии сдвигает начало массива на следующий элемент и уменьшает количество элементов в нем на один.
Вызывать можно вот так:

```
int n = ...  
float a[n];
...
printf("max: %f\n", rfmax(a + 1, n - 1, a[0]));
```

Однако, в Вашем  примере несколько другая процедура, которая перебирает элементы некоторого диапазона массива и возвращает индекс максимального в нем. Здесь по всем шагам рекурсии нам надо вместе с текущим максимумом тащить еще и его индекс, который в конце-концов и возвращается как результат.

Пожалуй, однострочник для нее выглядит несколько вычурно,  соответственно, рекурсивный вариант, максимально похожий на Ваш пример, можно написать так:

```
int ixfmax (float a[], int start, int end, float cmax, int icmax) {
  if (start > end)
    return icmax;
  if (cmax < a[start]) 
    cmax = a[icmax = start];
  return ixfmax(a, start + 1, end, cmax, icmax);
}
```

и вот так использовать его для поиска максимального элемента во всем массиве

```
  int imax = ixfmax(a, 1, n - 1, a[0], 0);
  printf("max: a[%d] = %f\n", imax, a[imax]);
```

Довольно естественно, что если при поиске мы сначала полагаем, что начальный элемент это максимум, то поиск проводим со следующего элемента. В самом деле,
зачем его сравнивать с самим собой?