# Nasm работа с указателями на массив через стек

Tags: ubuntu, ассемблер, g++

Есть такая c++ функция

```
extern int** GetSubOrders(int* order);
```

Необходимо запилить тело в ассемблерном модуле для nasm под ubuntu.
Вопрос такой: как работать с указателями в данном случае? т.е. получить order, вытащить из него значения, растолкать по субмассивам и вернуть указатель на массив указателей? Интересует asm код, спасибо.

Понятное дело, что order это адрес на первый элемент массива, но трудность в том как получить его значения из стека и таким образом прокрутить весь массив. Возвращать int** также через стек, но туда класть только адрес на массив адресов, которые в свою очередь были расположены где-то в переменной,  или расположить все адреса субмассивов?

Comment: если `order` это массив, то тогда в функцию нужно передавать размер массива или договориться о "последнем элементе". По другому конечно можно, но это все сильно компиляторозависимо и сильно бажно.

Comment: @KoVadim интересует сам механизм. все необходимые допущения, относительно добавления новых переменных в функцию или иной дополнительной информации, можно сделать.

Comment: ок. в `order` будет указатель (адрес) на первый (нулевой) элемент. Так как указатели скорее всего 4 байта, то добавив 4 к этому адресу, получите указатель на следующий элемент.

Comment: Почему вы решили возвращать что то через стек ? В большинстве соглашений о вызовах (вы кстати определите какое у вас соглашение используется) возвращаемое значение находится в  eax. Если значение больше 4х байт, то оно кладется на текущую вершину стека и в eax возвращается указатель на эту точку в стеке. int ** должен влезать в eax, если у вас 4х байтные указатели

Comment: @Mike 
">  int ** должен влезать в eax"

 не уверен, что понял правильно, т.е. в eax копировать адрес на массив с адресами subOrders, в которых в свою очередь находятся данные? Тогда сам массив с адресами subOrders располагать в произвольной переменной?

Comment: Напишите на c++ желаемый код и явно укажите в вопросе чем код, генерируемый компилятором не достаточен в вашем случае.  Вот [пример функции, которая работает с массивом без стека (возвращает указатель на наибольший элемент в переданном массиве): `++first` в ассемблере как         `addq    $4, %rdi` может выглядеть, где `first` это `int*`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519147/23044).

Comment: @persifal , по соглашениям stdcall, cdecl возвращаемое значение передается через регистр eax, т.е. чтобы сишный код получил из вашей функции значение указателя, в самой функции перед выходом нужно этот указатель положить в eax.

Comment: @persifal А память под ваши указатели должна зарезервировать вызывающая программа и вам передать, по хорошему. Либо вы сами выделяете память, правда не представляю как ибо вам надо будет вызывать C-шные функции выделения памяти. И тогда вызывающая программа должна будет освободить эту память после  использования. Можете конечно положить в стек, но тогда вызывающая программа должна эти указатели все использовать (скопировать куда нибудь себе) до того как вызовет любую другую функцию, что бы стек не затерся следующим вызовом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно определиться с [соглашением о вызове](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5), например, возьмите `__fastcall`, тогда, если `int` у вас 4 байта, то `ecx = order`. Тогда `[ecx]` - это нулевой элемент массива. Можете завести какой-нибудь цикл с помощью `edi`, например, чтобы через конструкцию `[ecx + 4*edi]` перечислить все элементы массива. Если же у вас режим `x64`, а не `x86`, то там иные соглашения о вызовах, и принцип немного иной. Если я верно помню (можно уточнить [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235286.aspx)), первый параметр передается через `rcx`, затем идут `rdx`, `r8` и `r9`. Проход по массиву такой же - через `[rcx + 4*rdi]`, когда `rdi = 0, 1, 2 ...`

Беда только одна - название функции, его вы не знаете. Узнать навание функции можно с помощью ошибки линкера. Когда начнёте линковать, вылезет ошибка, что функция такая-то с названием `какое-то-название` определена, но не реализована. (Например, в одном из моих проектов название такое страшное: `?add@AddAsm@@YIIPAIPBIII@Z`, хотя исходная функция назвалась `AddAsm::add`). Вот это название и нужно будет вписать в ассемблерный код. Ниже псевдокод (почти nasm), примерно похожий на то, что вам нужно (более конкретно не покажу, потому что я не предоставляю уровень конкретики ответа выше, чем конкретика вопроса). Кстати, слово `extern` не нужно.

```
[BITS 32]

global какое-то-название-функции ; Тут декларируется функция

section .code

какое-то-название-функции:  ; Тут точка входа в функцию.
  push edi     ; __fastcall обязан заботится о сохранении edi, esi и ebx

  xor edi, edi

.loop:  
  mov edx, [ecx + edi*4]
  ... Что-то делаем с edx ...
  lea edi, [edi + 1]   ; ++ edi
  cmp edi, некое-число ; Сколько итераций нужно
  jne .loop            

  pop edi

  mov eax, Бла-бла  ; Это результат работы функции, передаётся через eax.

  ret 0 ; Выход без корректировки стека
```

Отталкиваясь от этого, попробуйте решить свою задачу сами.

Comment: Чтобы не мучаться с name mangling, нужно обернуть объявление функции в коде с++ в блок `extern "C" { ... }`.

Comment: @insolor, и как тогда будут передаваться параметры?

Comment: Точно так же, как и без этого блока. Этот блок влияет на то, как имя функции будет представлено в объектном файле. Манглинг нужен только если есть несколько функций с одинаковым именем, но разными параметрами. Если такая функция только одна, то манглинг особого смысла не имеет. В любом случае, что с ним, что без него по факту количество параметров и их тип в скомпилированном исполняемом файле никак не проверяется.

Comment: Т.е. количество и тип параметров конечно же проверяется, но на этапе компиляции в объектный файл, по тому, как выглядит объявление внешней функции. Линкеру же важно, чтобы не было двух объектов с одинаковыми именами, а параметры функций он не проверяет.