# Рекурсивный поиск максимального элемента в массиве java

Tags: java, рекурсия

Не выдержал, нашел решение в сети, пытаюсь изобразить это на листе бумаги или ещё как-то, но не получается никак понять, как здесь это работает. Может кто-нибудь пожалуйста объяснить, что здесь всё таки происходит? возможно ли решить задачу без второго параметра max в сигнатуре метода? мозг сломал, а ведь ещё нужно и номер максимального элемента рекурсивно найти.

```
public static int findMax(int[] n, int max) {
    if (n.length > max) {
        int next = findMax(n, max + 1);
        return (n[max] > next) ? n[max] : next;
    } else {
        return n[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Найти максимум одномерного массива c помощью рекурсии C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519102/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой тестовый код:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class TestFindMax
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] a = {3,5,234,5,123,2,3,5};

        System.out.println(findMax(a, 0));
    }

    public static int findMax(int[] n, int max) {
        if (n.length > max) {
            int next = findMax(n, max + 1);
            System.out.println("next=" + next + " max=" + max);
            return (n[max] > next) ? n[max] : next;
        } else {
            return n[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Показывает вот такой результат:

```
next=3 max=7
next=5 max=6
next=5 max=5
next=5 max=4
next=123 max=3
next=123 max=2
next=234 max=1
next=234 max=0
234
```

Параметр *max* в данном случае немного сбивает с толку и не описывает своего реального назначения: он указывает на следующий сравниваемый элемент в массиве. Без него обойтись никак не возможно, а для правильной работы функции он должен быть выставлен в 0.

Чтобы можно было понять этот чудесный алгоритм, нужно раскрутить его до самой последней итерации, т.е когда выполнится блок `else` и вернет значение 0-го элемента массива:

```
if (n.length <= max)
{
    ...
} else { return n[0]; }
```

Собственно, именно на последней итерации мы и получаем результат

```
next=3 max=7
```

А дальше нужно выполнить обратный проход возврата значений внутри блока `if`

```
return (n[max] > next) ? n[max] : next;
```

Значение `next` будет результатом возврата предыдущей итерации.

1. `next = 3 (n[0])`
2. `return (n[7] > 3) ? n[7] : 3` само собой вернет `n[7] = 5` и `next = n[7]`
3. `return (n[6] > 5) ? n[6] : 5` вернет 5
4. ... и так далее

Comment: спасибо, с первого раза сложно понять. а как в таком случае рекурсивно вернуть номер максимального элемента в массиве?

Comment: @IlyaZhavoronkov возвращать класс, хранящий пару чисел, сравнение по 1 полю. 2 - поле номер. ну и `return ( new P(n[max],max) > next) ? new P(n[max],max) : next;`

Comment: ещё раз спасибо. ужас конечно для меня пока что. можете что-нибудь посоветовать в плане объяснения работы рекурсии? я смотрел курсы Головача Ивана, он там довольно подробно про суть рекурсии рассказал, а вот предсказать результат на подобных примерах не получается. На codingbat тоже много упражнений по рекурсии прорешал. И это тоже не помогает)

Comment: @IlyaZhavoronkov советую начать с математической базы рекурсии, еще раньше можно начать с математической индукции, постепенно переходить к рекурсивным алгоритмам.

Comment: @pavel можете привести код полностью? именно по поиску индекса, без возвращения самого максимального элемента.

Comment: @IlyaZhavoronkov некрасиво конечно, `if (max == n.length - 1) return max; int t = find(n,max+1); return n[t] > n[max]?t:max;`

Comment: @pavel у меня возвращает неверное значение, если в аргументах передавать массив и 0.

Comment: @IlyaZhavoronkov а у меня работает. http://ideone.com/EMEFmO