# Strlen рекурсивно

Tags: c, рекурсия

Вот код :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int mylen(char *s, int i)
{
if (*(s + i) == '\0') printf("%d",i);
else {
    return mylen(s, i + 1);

     }
}
void main(void) {
char s[] = "Hello";
mylen(s,0);
_getch();
}
```

Однако преподаватель спросил про то, какие возможны варианты , и написал следующее:

```
mylen(s)=0, если строка пустая (s==" ");
```

и

```
mylen(s)= 1+ mylen(s+1)
```

вот что это означает ? что за прибавления написаны , это из-за рекурсии? , поясните , пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                    "стр"
            mystrlen(^   ) // Строка - это указатель на её первый символ
        1 + mystrlen( ^  ) // Прибавили 1 к результату и к указателю
    1 + 1 + mystrlen(  ^ ) // Прибавили 1 к результату и к указателю
1 + 1 + 1 + mystrlen(   ^) // Пустая строка - надо вернуть 0
```

Ну и (с учётом того, что строка заканчивается 0-символом) получится такой код:

```
int mystrlen(char *s)
{
  return *s ? 1 + mystrlen(s+1) : 0;
}
```

Замечу, что к такой реализации, в отличие от твоей, компилятор не сможет применить оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии (из-за сложения с результатом) и глубина стека будет расти с каждым символом строки. Можно допилить до такого:

```
int mystrlen(char *s, int n)
{
  return !*s ? n : mystrlen(s+1, n+1);
}
```

---

А в твоём коде есть ошибка:

> ```
> if (*(s + i) == '\0') printf("%d",i);
> ```

Тут должно быть `return i`, иначе получается, что функция не возвращает значение, хотя должна. Даже несмотря на то, что возвращаемое значение нигде не используется, на x64 программа с таким кодом может иногда падать. Ну и ещё архитектурно неправильно выводить длину строки из функции, которая её просто считает - она должна посчитать и вернуть результат, а уже вызывающий код должен вывести на печать.

Comment: а разве тернарное условие - это чистый Си ?

Comment: @Elvin, да, это чистый си.

Comment: [по ассемблеру можно посмотреть](https://godbolt.org/g/6mgeYs), что действительно хвостовая рекурсия в чисто итеративный код превращается. [Ещё пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519147/23044)

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[] = { 's','t','r','i','n','g', '\0' };
```

Вызов 0: *(s + 0) == '\0' => `false` На самом деле: 's'
Вызов 1: *(s + 1) == '\0' => `false` На самом деле: 't'
.......
Вызов 6: *(s + 6) == '\0' => `true`
Передаваемый вторым аргументом i - это и есть длина исходной строки. Таким образом - при последнем вызове ф-ии ей был передан i равный 6, 6 - длина строки.